# Excel Duty List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a duty roster for my class.

Background:
We currently have weekday and weekend duties. People who do duties on weekdays get 1 point, while those who do on weekends get 2.

Problem:
I'm wondering how to code the table in excel such that whenever someone does a duty on a weekday, it recognizes that the person gets 1 point.

My roster is as such: (where A,B,C are row references)

A    Name|Points|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|

B    Name|Points|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|

C    Name|Points|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|Date duty is done on|

I've tried the following code, which checks if the date is a weekday, and to count the cell if it is:

```
{=SUM(--(if(A:A<>", WEEKDAY(A:A)={2,3,4,5,6}))}
```

For weekends, I create a separate column that counts weekends, but then I will double the points. Then in a column called *Points*, it will be the sum of the weekday and weekend points.

Unfortunately the above formula doesn't work as I keep getting `#NA` and `#VALUE` errors and in the end I'm unable to get the roster done.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, where the names are in column A, the points formulas are in column B and the dates are in the columns C to ZZ. So row 2 (columnheaders in row 1) could look like this:

> **2** John | 6 | 6/25/2016 | 6/26/2016 | 6/27/2016 | 6/28/2016 |

The formula that calculates the points in column B looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(2-NETWORKDAYS(C2:ZZ2+0,C2:ZZ2+0),--ISNUMBER(C2:ZZ2))
```

Just copy it down to the rest of the rows.

It works like this:

> 2-NETWORKDAYS(C2:ZZ2+0,C2:ZZ2+0)

will result in an array of 2's and 1's. 1 for a workday and 2 for a weekendday or a blank cell. Adding the 0 converts the ranges to arrays. NETWORKDAYS cannot work with ranges.

> --ISNUMBER(C2:ZZ2)

will create an array of 1's and zero's (-- will convert true to 1 and false to 0). 1 if the cell has a date(number) and 0 for blank cells. We need this to lose the results of the blank cells (2's) from the first array.

SUMPRODUCT will multiply the two arrays and sum the results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data as shown in the image below, where

- `Column A` has Names
- Points should be calculated in `Column B`
- `Column C, D, E` contains duty dates

[image]

Enter the following formula in the cell `B2` and drag/copy down as required.

```
=SUM(IF(((WEEKDAY(C2:E2)=7)+(WEEKDAY(C2:E2)=1))>0,2,1))
```

This is an array formula so comiit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.